# Generating Javascript class with constructor, getter and setter from Json Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js

Can anyone suggest, how we can generate the Javascript class that contains constructor, 
getters and setters from the JSON schema fields without any tools.

Example: I have the given below data schema

```
"data": {
                  "properties": {
                    "name": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "minLength": 1,
                      "maxLength": 256,
                      "title": "Name"
                    },
                    "description": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "minLength": 1,
                      "maxLength": 256,
                      "title": "Description"
                    }
                }
              }
```

I want to generate the below Model

```
'use strict';
                let name;
                let description;
                var _testSample;
                class SampleModel {

                    constructor() {

                        _testSample = {
                            data: {
                                'name': name,
                                'description': description
                            }
                        };
                    }

                    setName(name) {
                        _testSample.data.name = name;
                    }

                    setDescription(description) {
                        _testSample.data.description = description;
                    }
                }

                module.exports = SampleModel;
```

Can you please suggest if there are any API/Template engine which can generate these kind of classes from the JSON schema?

Can anyone suggest, how we can generate the Javascript class that contains constructor, 
getters and setters from the JSON schema fields without any tools.

I tried couple of apis like: json-schema-defaults, swagger codegen client, etc. but I was unable to generate/achieve it.

Comment: Please note: asking for tools or libraries or other third-party tools is considered off-topic here.

Comment: can you please provide some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we can generate the Model from the JSON/Schema with the help of the below API:

[json2model](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2model)!

The above API generates it in the C#, but we can **tweak the template** to suit your requirement.

It uses the Python templating engine Jinja.

[jinja-python templating engine](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/)!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nodejs, just write a script to parse it into the string you want.

```
import * as jsonClasses from "./my-json-classes-file";
import * as fs from "fs";

// add each line one at a time
let lines = ["use-string"];
for (let propname in jsonClasses) {
  lines.push(`let %{propname};`);
}

out.push("class MyClass");

... just keep doing this

// join the lines together
const rawFile = lines.join("\n");

// write it to a file
fs.writeFileSync("MyFileName.js", rawFile);
```

Then, there will generally be a way to make sure this script runs before you run/compile/build your project.  Or maybe you'll have to run it manually.

Point is, basic node is very able to take json and generate a text file.